# Proof check: let $X$ be $[0,\infty)$, and let $\Omega$ be a set containing $\varnothing,X$, and all $(a,\infty)$. Prove $\Omega$ is a topology on $X$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

The complete statement is: Let $X$ be the ray $[0, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$, and let $\Omega$ consist of $\varnothing$, $X$, and all rays $(a, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}_{0+}$. Prove $\Omega$ is a topology on $X$.

First we find a set-theoretical definition of $\Omega$: $\{\varnothing, X\}\cup\{(a,\infty):a\in\mathbb{R}_{0+}\}$. Then we verify the three usual conditions, by letting $A_1, A_2$ be any two arbitrary elements in $\{(a,\infty):a \in \mathbb{R}_{0+}\}$.

**Condition 1:** For all $\Omega_a, \Omega_b$ in $\Omega$, we have $\Omega_a \cup \Omega_b \subset \Omega$.

We have: that the union of $\varnothing$ with a nonempty set is that nonempty set; $(X \cup A_1) \subseteq X$; and $A_1 \cup A_2$ is identical to whichever of $A_1, A_2$ is larger.

Therefore,  the second condition holds.

**Condition 2:** For all $\Omega_a, \Omega_b$ in $\Omega$, we have $\Omega_a \cap \Omega_b \subset \Omega$.

We have: that the intersection of $\varnothing$ with a nonempty set is $\varnothing$; $(X\cap A_1)=A_1$; and $A_1 \cap A_2$ is whichever of the two is smaller.

Therefore, the second condition holds.

**Condition 3:** $\varnothing, X \in \Omega$. Trivially true.

Since the three conditions of the definition of a topology on a set hold, $\Omega$ is a topology on $X$. $\blacksquare$

Is this proof correct? Am I lacking formalization? I'm completely new to topology so I'm not too sure about it all.

Thank you very much!

(The exercise is from Elementary topology, problem textbook by Viro et al. page 11.)

Comment: It is not enough to check for finite union, you need to consider arbitrary unions.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thank you very much for reading through! I thought choosing an arbitrary $A_1,A_2$ would work in, but I see that isn't enough now that you mention it... would you have a hint on how I could proceed in that sense?

Comment: Consider a family (which may be infinite) $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ and show that $\cup_{i\in I} A_i$ is in $\Omega$

Comment: You can essentially do the same proof. You just need to be more careful by what "whichever is larger" means in this context.

Comment: thank you very much to you both for your feedback! I would consider that these are full answers, I don't know about you. but in any case, thank you!